# Modify Pandas Market Calendar so all Calendar Month-End Days are Treated as Business Days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function to shift a date n business days using `pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay` and `holidays` from `pandas_market_calendars`:

```
def _shift_n_bdays(d: date | datetime, n=-1, holidays=default_holidays) -> date:
       return (d + CDay(n, holidays=holidays)).date()
```

I get holidays from

```
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
mcal.get_calendar(calendar).holidays().holidays
```

I am looking to modify an existing `pandas_market_calendar` (`SIFMAUSExchangeCalendar`) so that all days that fall on a calendar month-end are treated as a business day - even if such day falls on a weekend or holiday.

Here is my attempt to modify the existing `SIFMAUSExchangeCalendar` to achieve this but it still thinks 2022-12-31 is not a business day.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from pandas_market_calendars.calendars.sifma import SIFMAUSExchangeCalendar

class ModifiedSIFMACalendar(SIFMAUSExchangeCalendar):
    def valid_days(self, start_date, end_date, tz='UTC'):
        # Generate the standard valid days using the parent class method
        valid_days = super().valid_days(start_date, end_date, tz)

        # Convert to set for faster lookup
        valid_days_set = set(valid_days)

        # Create a new list to hold the modified set of valid days
        modified_valid_days = list(valid_days)

        # Generate a date range for the entire period
        all_days = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

        # Iterate over each day in the date range
        for day in all_days:
            # Check if the day is a month end
            if (day + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).month != day.month:
                # If it's a month-end day and not already a valid day, add it
                if day not in valid_days_set:
                    modified_valid_days.append(day)

        # Return the modified list of valid days
        return pd.DatetimeIndex(modified_valid_days).sort_values()
    
    def holidays(self):
        # Extract the holiday calendar from the CustomBusinessDay object
        standard_holidays = super().holidays().holidays

        # Filter out holidays that are at the end of a month
        modified_holidays = [holiday for holiday in standard_holidays
                             if not (holiday + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).month != holiday.astype(int) % 12 + 1]

        return CustomBusinessDay(holidays=pd.DatetimeIndex(modified_holidays))
```